# Logitech C922 webcam not detected on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, usb, webcam, logitech, camera

I just got a Logitech C922x (USB) webcam which I need to install on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I tried on Cheese and on Skype, but it says that the device is not detected.

Any idea? Thanks a lot for your help.

When I type `journalctl --follow` in the Terminal and plug in the USB webcam, it says:

```
Sep 27 18:06:32 myPC kernel: usb 3-1.1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Sep 27 18:06:32 myPC kernel: usb 3-1.1.3.2: config index 0 descriptor too short (expected 2503, got 1277)
Sep 27 18:06:32 myPC kernel: usb 3-1.1.3.2: config 1 has an invalid descriptor of length 54, skipping remainder of the config
Sep 27 18:06:32 myPC kernel: usb 3-1.1.3.2: config 1 has 2 interfaces, different from the descriptor's value: 4
Sep 27 18:06:32 myPC kernel: usb 3-1.1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=085c
Sep 27 18:06:32 myPC kernel: usb 3-1.1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Sep 27 18:06:32 myPC kernel: usb 3-1.1.3.2: Product: C922 Pro Stream Webcam
Sep 27 18:06:32 myPC kernel: usb 3-1.1.3.2: SerialNumber: ********
Sep 27 18:06:37 myPC kernel: usb 3-1.1.3.2: can't set config #1, error -110
Sep 27 18:06:37 myPC mtp-probe[3175]: checking bus 3, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:05:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1.3/3-1.1.3.2"
Sep 27 18:06:37 myPC mtp-probe[3175]: bus: 3, device: 12 was not an MTP device
Sep 27 18:06:37 myPC fwupd[3007]: failed to add USB device: 046d:085c is not supported: USB error on device 046d:085c : Entity not found [-5]
Sep 27 18:06:37 myPC upowerd[1550]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:05:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1.3/3-1.1.3.2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I manage to get it to work by plugging the Webcam into a USB 3 port directly on the computer (not using a usb hub or any other intermediate) and then rebooting the computer. 
Cheers
(Works on Ubuntu 18.04LTS and 18.10)

Comment: Problems about microphone , in my case plugging the webcam into a USB 3 port then log out and log in the pc. Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Try typing alsamixer in your Terminal and rising all inputs. Also before this, did you check the input source in your Ubuntu System Settings?